# Como crear una etiqueta <a> dentro de un popover data-bs-content

Tags: javascript, php, html

Tengo el siguiente contenido

```
 <div class="container">
            <a href='#' data-bs-toggle="popover" title="<?=$nombrep?>"
                data-bs-content="<a href='<?= base_url() ?>Grafico/<?= $idp  ?>' class='btn btn-success'>Ver</a>">
                <img src='<?= base_url() ?>assets/img/fotosPerfil/<?= $principalp  ?>' class='imgRedonda' /></a>
        </div>
```

el problema que tengo, es lo que hay dentro de data-bs-content no me lo convierte en un enlace para que las personas opriman y se redirigan al enlace que quiero.

estoy usando el javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();  
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('data-bs-content', function () {
        var popover = $(this).next();
        var content = popover.find('.data-bs-content');
        content.html("<a href='https://www.myconnectmind.com/Grafico/11'>Link dentro del popover</a>");
    });
});
```

para que me convierta la etiqueta adentro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero me sigue apareciendo de esta manera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como indica la [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/popovers/#options) tienes que poner `data-bs-html="true"` para que acepte contenido como HTML

Demo:

```js
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs-html="false" data-bs-content="<a href='https://www.myconnectmind.com/Grafico/11'>Link dentro del popover</a>" >
 data-bs-html="false"
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-content="<a href='https://www.myconnectmind.com/Grafico/11'>Link dentro del popover</a>" >
  data-bs-html="true"
</button>
```

Comment: Te amo, se me olvidaba buscar en la documentación.